# Removing the related videos from an embedded youtube video

Tags: html, video, youtube, embed

Is there an easy way to do this still? This snippet used to work but it appears to be broken now.

```
      <iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="510" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/5yle1USyhCY&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, just noticed that there is typically an option for it.
http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171780

For the video I'm embedding, I don't see that option though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahh, silly me. Should have been a question mark instead of an ampersand.

That url needs to be:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/5yle1USyhCY?rel=0
```

instead of:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/5yle1USyhCY&rel=0
```

Comment: You are correct regarding *related* videos. But recently Youtube also display 'more videos' as suggestion when we are using even 'rel=0'. The different is that the *more videos* appear from same youtube user account (which video is being played in embeded media player). How can we disable this panel as well?